# working with geojson and vincent on python?

Tags: python, geojson

I want to import a geojson file into python so I can map it with a visualization package vincent and merge with other data in a pandas data frame.

To be specific, the said geojson file is: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/justgrimes/a63e8ec28868d8ce337e/raw/13cd7d8867e579d8b4f6b44f002a99940fba0504/DCNeighborhoodBoundariesWaPo.geojson. It's a map of DC with neighborhoods, put together by Justin Grimes.

Right now, I'm just trying to visualize this map on notebook. Here's my code:

```
import vincent
map=r'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/justgrimes/a63e8ec28868d8ce337e/raw/13cd7d8867e579d8b4f6b44f002a99940fba0504/DCNeighborhoodBoundariesWaPo.geojson'

geo_data = [{'name': 'countries',
             'url': map,
             'feature': "features"}] 
vis = vincent.Map(geo_data=geo_data, scale=5000) 
vis
```

but I have nothing in the output. What am I doing wrong here?

I don't yet know much about GIS and Python.

Answer (score 3):

You have to load Vincent JS parts with `vincent.initialize_notebook()`

You need to transform the GeoJSON to TopoJSON (use [Mapshaper](http://mapshaper.org)) as Vincent support only TopoJSON (or I missed something too). See the official doc to understand [TopoJSON](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki)

The key `DCNeighborhoodBoundariesWaPo` in `'feature': "DCNeighborhoodBoundariesWaPo"` was deduced from TopoJSON `objects`

You do not display you visualisation with `vis.display()`

See below working sample for a complete overview.

```
import vincent

vincent.initialize_notebook()

map=r'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ThomasG77/9e05f8cd04f0406e4529/raw/1974a51fbe081c83c3c20da7bcdb091a3d6604e2/DCNeighborhoodBoundariesWaPo.json'

geo_data = [{'name': 'whatever',
             'url': map,
             'feature': "DCNeighborhoodBoundariesWaPo"}] 
vis = vincent.Map(geo_data=geo_data, scale=150000, translate=[-40480], projection='albersUsa') 

vis.display()
```

A last remaining problem is the fact I was able to zoom to DC but without using really a recipe (more try/test...), with translate (IMO, Vega/Vincent sucks for this when zooming on a specific part of a country or region)

If you have a better way of doing for the last part, I will be happy to learn how!

Comment: Thanks for your response! this is a really basic question, but after I convert the file from GeoJson to TopoJson(or just Json, using Mapshaper), how would I establish a url path to put in map? the path to my hard drive where the Json file is saved seems to be not working, giving me the 'Loading failed' error message.

Comment: the url issue aside, I also get an error at this line: vis = vincent.Map(geo_data=geo_data, scale=150000, translate=[-40480], projection='albersUsa'). The error is len(center) must = 2. did you not have this issue?

Comment: For 1st comment, I usually do use default included Python web server e.g http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/tech-tip-really-simple-http-server-python For 2nd comment, it was tested and worked but I didn't exactly checked my version of Vincent (maybe related to your issue).

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing `vincent` very well, could I offer that your `map` variable is just a string and not the resulting geojson you expect? Or you could validate the geojson at http://geojsonlint.com/

Comment: this geojson file is validated

Comment: Example from here has projection info, this isn't in your code. Does that help? http://vincent.readthedocs.org/en/latest/charts_library.html?highlight=map

Comment: The remote data is invalid if following JSON spec. I tested with http://jsonlint.com and it fails. You can't go further if you don't do local correction.

Comment: Sorry, I did have a wrong link there. please see edits.

Comment: well, everything works for me from your code. I can get `<class 'vincent.charts.Map'>` using `print type(vis)`...is your code above everything you want to do? or am I missing something?

Comment: ok, think I unerstand. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26132380/vincent-visualizations-are-not-displaying-from-the-command-line) might help